# How in batch file set to variable up level path

Tags: batch-file

I need in batch file set in variable up level of path. Fo example, I have next structure of folder:

> C:\Temp\Script

In this script exist my batch file:

```
SET mypath=%~dp0 :: Set path C:\Temp\Script
SET UpLevel="%mypath:~0,-1%.."
echo UpLevel ::need show C:\Temp\
```

So how it's write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%cd%") do echo %%~dpa
```

or

```
@echo off

pushd ..
set "uplevel=%cd%"
popd

echo %uplevel%
```

or

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
set "_path_=%~dp0"
set _path_=%_path_:~0,-1%

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%_path_%") do echo %%~dpa
```

?